# I am using PHP and MySQL my input box only updates integer values I want to update character values too

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to update my database through a input box in html. So far everything works exception of the name. It wont update the name if its actual characters such as 'toys'. It will however update if I type in numbers such as 45634. My database value for "name" is varchar(15).

Here is my code to update the name in the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $data = getPosts();
    $update_Query = "UPDATE `item` SET `name`=$data[4] WHERE itemID = $data[0]";
    try{
        $update_Result = mysqli_query($conn, $update_Query);

    if($update_Result)
    {
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
        {
            echo 'Data Updated';
        }else{
            echo 'Data Not Updated';
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Error Update '.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

My HTML box is here just the name part of it

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>"><br><br>
```

and this is how I store the value name there is others but they work fine only having trouble with the name

```
function getPosts()
{
    $posts = array();
    $posts[4] = $_POST['name'];
    return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `name` type is `VARCHAR`, you have to put string into it, not integer. Try to change `` SET `name`=$data[4] `` into `` SET `name`='".$data[4]."' ``.

Comment: worked like a charm I was unaware you needed both ' '  " ". I originally had tried it as  `name`='$data[4]' Got it working now though thanks.